# Filter txt files by the creation date

Tags: c#, datetime, zip

I'm doing a tool that is supposed to zip some ".txt" files by the dates of creation.

What I want is to compress in Zip all the txt files created in the same day from a specific folder. I can't find a way to filter the files by the dates.

Comment: What did you try already? Can you share your current code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [FAQ] and [ask] couple of times before you move on. People love to see your effort first before they show their.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quick and dirty:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

public static void GetTxtFiles()
        {
            var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo("pathToFolder");
            var specificDay = new DateTime(2022, 06, 15).Date;

            var txtFiles = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.txt")
                .Where(x => x.CreationTime.Date.Equals(specificDay))
                .ToList();
            if (txtFiles.Count == 0)
                throw new FileNotFoundException("No txt files have been found");
            ArchiveFiles("pathToZip", txtFiles);
        }

        private static string ArchiveFiles(string zipCreatePath, List<FileInfo> filesToZip)
        {
            if (File.Exists(zipCreatePath))
                File.Delete(zipCreatePath);

            using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(zipCreatePath, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
            {
                foreach (var file in filesToZip)
                {
                    archive.CreateEntryFromFile(file.FullName, file.Name);
                }
            }
            return zipCreatePath;
        }
```

Comment: Note that .CreationTime can return incorrect value which is known as File System Tunneling in OS. You can avoid that by adding txtFile.Refresh() for each newly added file before accessing the txtFile.CreationTime value.

Answer (score 3):

The File library has a method [GetCreationTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getcreationtime?view=net-6.0) which takes the path as a string.

Using this method, you could filter your files.